# How to use string variables in Oracle SQL WHERE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am attempting to use some string variables to return data from an Oracle SQL DB. I am able to `define` the variables and then use them in my `select`, but then no results are returned. When I just type out an example `select` using the values I want in the variables then I get results.

Here is the script I've got so far:

```
define Team_Name = concat(concat('''','100.100.1112'),'''');
define not_tcode_name1 = concat(concat('''','PTO'),'''');
define not_tcode_name2 = concat(concat('''','BRV'),'''');
define start_date = to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy');
define end_date = to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy');

select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = &Team_Name
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between &start_date and &end_date
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name1
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name2
;
```

When I run this the **Query Results** are all blank. And the **Script Output** looks like this:

```
old:select wd.dept_name
   , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
   , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
   , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = &Team_Name
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between &start_date and &end_date
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name1
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name2

new:select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = concat(concat('''','100.100.1112'),'''')
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''','PTO'),'''')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''','BRV'),'''')
>>Query Run In:Query Result 1
```

So I try running the **new** code:

```
select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = concat(concat('''','100.100.1112'),'''')
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''','PTO'),'''')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''','BRV'),'''');
```

And that returns nothing for each column.

However if I remove the `concat(concat('''',` and `),'''')` from around the 3 variables for `dept_name`, and `tcode_name` then it works and returns values. Looks like this:

```
select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = '100.100.1112'
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> 'PTO'
    and wd.tcode_name <> 'BRV'
    ;
```

I have tried with out the `concat` but then I just get an error:

> SQL command not properly ended
>
> Error at line: 13 Column 29

The `Script Output` gives me this for the **new**:

```
select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = 100.100.1112
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> PTO
    and wd.tcode_name <> BRV
```

So the variables, though strings, are not being treated as strings. They don't automatically get the single quotes around them. And using `concat` isn't working either as that just adds it to the string instead of concating to single quotes.

I have also tried putting the `concat` in the `where` clause around where I'm using them, but then I get a different error saying:

> missing right parenthesis
>
> Error at Line: 13 Column 28

And I see that the `Script Output` shows this for the **new**:

```
select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = concat(concat('''',100.100.1112),'''')
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''',PTO),'''')
    and wd.tcode_name <> concat(concat('''',BRV),'''')
```

Now the strings don't have single quotes around them, so the `concat` fails thinking the first one is a number with too many decimals.

So, my question is, how do I get the variables to work right?

There could be anywhere from a few dozen to several hundred thousand returned rows. And I need to be able to copy them out to Excel or Word so using `declare` and a `cursor` and outputting using the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` isn't going to work for me I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, you made it work, but some pieces of code don't make much sense. For example:

```
define not_tcode_name1 = to_char('PTO');
```

`'PTO'` already is a string, so converting it to one (with the help of `to_char` function) is as if you applied `to_number` to `1` (although it already is a number) or - what we often see - `to_date` to `sysdate` (although `sysdate` is a function that returns `date` datatype).

---

From my point of view, what you should have done in the first place is to simply enclose substitution variables - that represent strings - into single quotes.

```
SQL> help define

 DEFINE
 ------

 Specifies a substitution variable and assigns a CHAR value to it, or
 lists the value and variable type of a single variable or all variables.

 DEF[INE] [variable] | [variable = text]
```

I don't have your table so I'll use Scott's sample schema and its `emp` table that contains info about employees. I'm interested in someone called `KING`.

This is what you did:

```
SQL> define v_ename = 'KING'
SQL> select empno, job, sal from emp where ename = &v_ename;
select empno, job, sal from emp where ename = KING
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "KING": invalid identifier
```

This is what you should have done:

```
SQL> select empno, job, sal from emp where ename = '&v_ename';
                                                   ^        ^
     EMPNO JOB              SAL                    |        |
---------- --------- ----------                 single quotes here
      7839 PRESIDENT       5000

SQL>
```

---

What about **dates**? They aren't strings. This is King's full record:

```
SQL> select * From emp where ename = 'KING';

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE           SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-Nov-1981       5000                    10
```

OK, so he was hired on 17th of November 1981. Let's set substitution variable to that value:

```
SQL> define v_hiredate = '17-Nov-1981'
SQL> select ename, job, sal from emp where hiredate = '&v_hiredate';

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       5000
```

That *worked*, but only because `v_hiredate` - which is a **string** (have a look at what `help define` says) - matches date format which is recognizable by Oracle. What if I modify default date format for current session?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy.mm.dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select ename, job, sal from emp where hiredate = '&v_hiredate';
select ename, job, sal from emp where hiredate = '17-Nov-1981'
                                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Right; it doesn't work any more because Oracle was incapable of converting string `'17-Nov-1981'` into a valid `date` value.

If I match new format model, it works:

```
SQL> define v_hiredate = '1981.11.17'
SQL> select ename, job, sal from emp where hiredate = '&v_hiredate';

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       5000

SQL>
```

---

So, carefully with that you're doing.

If that particular query (you posted) is the ONLY query you're running, perhaps you'd rather simply put all values into `where` clause, applying appropriate function(s) when necessary. If there are two (or more) queries, then yes - it makes sense to define substitution variables at the beginning of the script and use them wherever needed.

Comment: This way works with just adding the `'` before and after the variable in the where clause. I didn't know that would work, I had thought it would then treat the variable name as the string I was looking for so I had not tried that.

Comment: This was just an example about what I am attempting to do. The variables will be used in a few different places in the full query that I am running.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to get this working is to use `to_char` when `defining` the variables, like this:

```
define Team_Name = to_char('100.100.1112');
define not_tcode_name1 = to_char('PTO');
define not_tcode_name2 = to_char('BRV');
define start_date = to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy');
define end_date = to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy');

select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = &Team_Name
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between &start_date and &end_date
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name1
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name2
;
```

Now when I run this I get the `Script Output` like this:

```
old:select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = &Team_Name
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between &start_date and &end_date
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name1
    and wd.tcode_name <> &not_tcode_name2

new:select wd.dept_name
    , wd.tcode_name "Time Code"
    , wd.htype_name "Hour Type"
    , wd.wrkd_minutes "Minutes Worked"
from workbrain.VIEW_MOD_WORK_DETAIL wd
where wd.dept_name = to_char('100.100.1112')
    and wd.wrkd_work_date between to_date('28/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('11/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and wd.tcode_name <> to_char('PTO')
    and wd.tcode_name <> to_char('BRV')
>>Query Run In:Query Result
```

And I get results returned from the query. I can now update the variables to whatever I need them to be and have results returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a new answer, using BIND Variables, "properly" ... from what I'm seeing in previous answers, they're just hacking together string macro substitution, which is very poor option for a few reasons (ie performance, sql injection to name a couple).

Very simple sample to show how to use. Once you can reference the bind variable in the SQL statement, you can reference it anyway in the sql (ie where, order by , anywhere ..

Note this works in both sql*plus, and in sqldeveloper (run the entire thing as a script)

```
var team_name  varchar2(20);
var test_val   number;
var start_date varchar2(20);

begin
   :team_name := '100.100.1112';
   :test_val := 123;
   :start_date := '28/11/2021';
end;
/

select :team_name as team_name,
       :test_val   as test_val,
       to_date(:start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')  as start_date
   from dual;

TEAM_NAME                          TEST_VAL START_DATE
-------------------------------- ---------- --------------------
100.100.1112                            123 28-nov-2021 00:00:00

1 row selected
```

The first section just defines your variables to be used.
Note, we don't have a DATE data type at this level in sql, so we have to store it as a string.  we handle the to_date conversion in the query.

Next we jump into plsql block to assign the binds.  (I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but this isn't hard in any case ) ..
Now the values are "locked in" . you're free to use them in subsequent queries .. as proper BIND variables .. not strings.  This typically allows queries to perform better (ie using BINDs, not splicing strings into queries).

It also avoids all the funny character juggling everyone is doing :)

Hope this helps!